# Prevent SlidingUpPanelLayout from hiding

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am using a `SlidingUpPanelLayout` in each activity of my app. I want the `drawer` to be either collapsed (and display a sort of mini player) or fully opened.

My base class for all activities overrides `onBackPressed()` and when pressed if the `drawer` is opened, it calls:

```
setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);
```

But the effect is different in the activities of my app.

In one activity (the main/home activity), if press back (or click on the drawer), the drawer gets collapsed. =>good!

In all other activities, if press back (or click on the drawer), the drawer gets hidden (I can see in `LogCat` 'onPanelHidden') => Not good.

I want pressing back or touching the drawer to collapse the drawer in all activities (and never hide it). How can I prevent the drawer from being hidden?

***Update***
This only seem to happen if I programmatically show the action bar (Sherlock) when I detect that the drawer is closing

```
  @Override
  public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
      Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
      if (slideOffset < mPreviousSlideOffset) {
          showActionBar()
       }
     ...
     mPreviousSlideOffset = slideOffset;
    }
```

In that case I can see in my logs that the slideOffset can take a negative value.

If I only show the action bar when onPanelCollapsed() is called, the drawer does not get hidden in any of my activities. (But only showing the action bar at this stage does not look fluid or natural)

Comment: It not make sense, maybe the handle is there but just not visible?

Comment: I have updated my question, I don't think it's just not visible as i can see in the logs 'onPanelHidden' rather than 'onPanelCollapsed' which i see in my main/home activity.